# Mongodb multidimensional data aggregation/deduplication

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have a collection containing data similiar to this:

```
{
dimension1:a,
dimension2:b,
dimension3:c,
dimension4:d,
dimension5:e,
value: x
}
```

there is a finite number of values that `a,b,c,d,e` can have. Therefore it is possible to see two rows with identical dimensions and different stored values, like this:

```
{ dimension1:1, dimension2:1, dimension3:1, dimension4:1, dimension5:1, value: 12 }
{ dimension1:1, dimension2:1, dimension3:1, dimension4:1, dimension5:1, value: 34 }
```

I would like to aggregate objects with matching dimensions and replace them with one object with a sum of values.

I am aware of the fact that I can do it with mapReduce, but is there a way to do it simpler/faster or even assure that my insert statement would add to an existing value if there is one?

[edit]

I also see that db.collection.group() seems designed to do such a thing, but it can't handle my size of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want an [Upsert With Modifier](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers). This would satisfy your second approach, so that you insert a row if no matching row exists, or just add the value if a matching row does exist.

So you example would be something like:

```
db.mycollection.update( { dimension1: a, ... dimension5: e }, { $inc: { value: x } }, true); //the 'true' is the param that makes this update an upsert
```

If you want to insert all the individual values then aggregate them later I would suggest you aggregated them to a separate collection (to avoid confusion). Probably the easiest way to do this would be with a map/reduce rather than a group, as you can simply set the output options of the map/reduce to merge its output into the aggregate collection with options like this: `out : {reduce: "aggregatedcollection"}`.

Comment: I already knew about merging mapReduce outputs, but the upsert is a new great discovery for me. Huge thanks!

Comment: For future reference: upsert on large collections is almost as slow as select+update